# Date Module / Date Repeat: Hourly or Minutely Recurrence?

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm setting up a Drupal 7 based calendaring system ,and the Date module has been super amazing; it does pretty much everything I need out of the box. However, correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't look like there's a way to set an event to reoccur, say, once every hour.

Do you have any idea for the best way to accomplish this?
I know PHP fairly well, so I'm game for writing code, but I have no idea where to start. Do I need to create a custom module that implements the Date Repeat API? What form would take, and how would it integrate with the existing Date module? Is this an unreasonably huge undertaking for a Drupal newbie?

Answer (score -1):

Recurring events are handled in good old unix cron, see (http://drupal.org/cron). But there is a more, Php way .. Poor Man's Cron, see http://drupal.org/project/poormanscron (in D6, part of core in D7).

Basically, since some hosts didn't allow cron jobs Poor Man's Cron simply "hooked" a bit of code into each page using Ajax. If an amount of time had past it would run cron.php (which in turn calls drupal_run_cron()).

Either way ... you need to put your task into the cron queue, make sure your site is set up correctly and let the core system execute it. If your going to use a custom module see

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron_queue_info/7

Comment: This is a different kind of event.  Greg's events pertain to the Date Repeat API.